# Embed a video in a pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf with ruby on rails and am able to generate a pdf with images and texts, but no videos. Is it possible to do it? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wicked_pdf is basically just a wrapper around wkhtmltopdf which uses the WebKit engine to convert HTML to PDF. If I understand [this post](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=549#c1) correctly, wkhtmltopdf relies on a specific version of WebKit built for QT which currently doesn't support that tag. So the short answer is no, the long answer is to start asking the wkhtmltopdf people when the `video` tag will be supported.

Comment: Thanks chris, I've asked antialize from the wkhtmltopdf project, he doesn't have an answer for the moment. Will have to look for something else!